# Is it possible for an app to respond to a push notification?

Tags: ios

Periodically, my app needs to download some data from my website, but instead of polling the website, I was wondering if there was a way my site could "push" the data to the app when its ready ?

I would like to do this programmatically, without the user having to choose to download this..

Comment: Maybe this'll help you https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/ios-push-notification-background-fetch-demystified-7090358bb66e it contains silent push and background fetch

Comment: have you tried you using silent push notification and background fetch?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options here:

1. Setup a Web Socket between your backend and the apps, which enables a communication channel where the backend can push required data to your app. However this architecture will drain your battery, since WebSocket requires to persist an open connection to your backend;
2. Send a silent notification to your device, which should trigger a call to the required service or process of downloading new data. This should be easier and less energy consuming implementation.

Comment: Isn't the push notification api for getting a response from users ? I don't think my app will know its received the push notification. Is that right ?

Comment: What do you mean by `getting a response from users`?

Comment: Push Notifications are emitted by backend to the device. There are 2 types of push notifications: a common one, which is displayed in the Notification Center of the device and within the app and a silent one, which is not displayed but still arrives in the respective applications notification handling functions.